# Visual Studio: Pushed solution to Team Services but won't push submodule

Tags: git, azure-devops

I'm having trouble connecting my team to my code because the submodule did not get pushed during the initial commit. It shows up as the only change that needs to be committed, but when I try to commit it, I get an error that says "fatal: unexpected sequence in commit output." I've looked everywhere and it seems I'm the only one having this problem. Of course, my team cannot pull my code because it does not contain the submodule. Has anyone else experienced this before?

Answer (score 5):

I faced similar issue while trying to commit using visual studio. The issue was because some of the changed files were not saved. I clicked "SaveAll" and try again. This time it worked

Answer (score 0):

For **adding a submodule for git repo and push to remote**, you should use these commands:

```
git submodule add <sub repo URL>
git commit 
git push
```

Then the submodule will be pushed to remote repo successfully.

To **pull changes from remote (including submodules)** for other developers:

```
git pull
git submodule update --recursive
```

To **clone the remote repo with submodules**:

```
git clone <URL> --recursive
```

Or select **Recursively Clone Submodules** for using VS to clone the repo.
[image]

Comment: Excellent. Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You can mark it as answer since it helps you solve the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I occurred with " fatal: unexpected sequence in commit output" error on project.
I found hidden folder .vs and .git at the current project folder. (Not solution folder)

When I delete them, unexpected sequence in commit output error of project is disappear and push works successfully

Comment: Do you event know what .git and .vs folders do?